# How to build a react native project for iOS in windows pc

Tags: ios, windows, react-native, build, eas

I am new in react native and want to build a ios app but i don't have iphone to test it so how can i test the build app on my windows pc.
I have launched ios app with command:
`eas build -p ios`
but what about next ?